# Automatically update a dockerfile when new versions of the base image are available

Tags: docker, github-actions, build-automation

Does anyone know of automation for automatically updating the digests referenced in a dockerfile when new upstream versions are released, as denoted by new tags with higher semver?

I've a project on github which builds a binary using a golang alpine image (e.g golang:1.21.3-alpine3.18), then copies the compiled binary in to the official alpine image (e.g. alpine:3.18.4) and releases it.
I'm digest pinning these images, and would like to have a github action or job which runs every week and checks for a more modern golang image where it chooses the highest golang version, then the highest alpine version and opens a PR to update the dockerfile with this, and the equivalent alpine version.
Does anyone know of existing automation to do this, or have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to be more specific. You've tagged this [tag:github-actions], for example, so _"job which runs every week"_ -> https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule

Comment: check out dependabot https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem

Or renovatebot https://docs.renovatebot.com/docker/

Comment: Renovatebot was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @jessehouwing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github Dependabot or Mend RenovateBot can automatically verify your dependincies, including docker base images, and will submit pull requests to alert you an update is available.